# Creating an STL container of `container< container<Base> >`

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Is there a way to do

```
container< container<Base> >
```

When you have a bunch of `container<Derived>`s that you wish to keep together (to iterator over?)

A concrete example follows.

Say you have

```
struct Animal { } ;
struct Dog : public Animal { } ;
struct StripedDog : public Dog { } ;
struct Cat : public Animal { } ;
struct SpottedCat : public Cat { } ;
```

You wish to keep collections of Cats, SpottedCats, Dogs & StripedDogs, in vectors or lists naturally,

```
vector<Dog*> doggies ;
vector<StripedDog*> stripedDoggies ;
vector<Cat*> catties ;
vector<SpottedCat*> spottedCatties ;
```

You wish to iterate over ALL animals, however, so you wish to slam references to all dogs & cats collections into a single object,

```
vector< vector<Animal *>* > zoo ;

zoo.push_back( &doggies ) ;
zoo.push_back( &stripedDoggies ) ;
zoo.push_back( &catties ) ;
zoo.push_back( &spottedCatties ) ;
```

So now you can

```
feed( zoo ) ;
```

Of course, this doesn't compile.  The vectors of cats & dogs are not `vector<Animal*>`, but rather vectors of their concrete types. Without retaining **redundant lists** and without losing the concrete type info (ie NOT using lists of base type `Animal*` as in `vector<Animal*> stripedDoggies`), is there a way to achieve equivalent behavior from C++?

Comment: Not directly, no. Why? because `vector<Base*>` and `vector<Derived*>` are not related. And it could lead to subtle errors.

Comment: No magical tricks anywhere?

Comment: With templates and composition, but not directly.

Comment: If you could do that, then you could also do `zoo[0]->push_back(new Cat());`, and suddenly, you have a cat in your doggies collection.

Comment: "You wish to iterate over ALL animals" would an iterator/range be sufficient?

Comment: Because you're trying to solve.... what ? I'm just thinking when in my lifetime I would be faced with having to do this, in particular with the restrictions you've systematically established, to solve ... ?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to have a *direct* call without creating an intermediate object? As in `feed( doggies, stripedDoggies, catties, spottedCatties );`?

Comment: @DanielFrey I think that is precisely what he's looking for).

Comment: Well, in my program I have several distinct types of objects that need to be stored in concrete typed vectors, just like this (ie a single array of `Animal*` is not sufficient, organizationally speaking).  Quite a few operations (such as `feed` in this metaphor) need to be applied to __all objects__ that live in all of these array types.  So it would be convenient and syntactically clean to be able to call `feed( zoo )` as I outlined here.  Other operations (such as `walk`) only need to be applied to the `Dog` class and its derivatives.

Comment: This is called [tag:covariance], and is not directly supported by C++.

Comment: Doesn't Boost have an iterator thing that you can create over a set of collections then iterate over the entire thing? Seems like what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you're looking at something like this, but not quite sure. Let me know if it isn't near to what you need and I'll drop it for favor of someone that does. The output demonstrates the virtual `feed()` operation does its business appropriately. Arranging a potential variadic parameter pack to that function would take me some time to cook on for awhile, and I'm not even sure it is possible.

But this should get you close.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

// base. enforces inheritance by SFINAE
template<typename Base, typename T, template<typename, typename...> class V>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type
invoke(void (Base::*func)(), const class V<T*>& vec)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    for (auto p : vec)
        (p->*func)();
}

// chain.
template<typename Base, typename T, template<typename, typename...> class V, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type
invoke(void (Base::*func)(), const class V<T*>& vec, Args... args)
{
    invoke(func, vec);
    invoke(func, args...);
}

int main()
{
    struct Animal
    {
        virtual void feed()
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }
    } ;

    struct Dog : public Animal
    {
        void feed()
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }
    } ;
    struct StripedDog : public Dog {};
    struct Cat : public Animal {};
    struct SpottedCat : public Cat {};

    std::vector<Dog*> doggies ;
    std::vector<StripedDog*> stripedDoggies ;
    std::vector<Cat*> catties ;
    std::vector<SpottedCat*> spottedCatties ;

    Dog dog;
    doggies.push_back(&dog);

    StripedDog sdog;
    stripedDoggies.push_back(&sdog);

    Cat cat;
    catties.push_back(&cat);

    invoke(&Animal::feed, doggies, stripedDoggies, catties, spottedCatties);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type invoke(void (Base::*)(), const class V<T *> &) [Base = Animal, T = Dog, V = vector]
virtual void main()::Dog::feed()
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type invoke(void (Base::*)(), const class V<T *> &) [Base = Animal, T = StripedDog, V = vector]
virtual void main()::Dog::feed()
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type invoke(void (Base::*)(), const class V<T *> &) [Base = Animal, T = Cat, V = vector]
virtual void main()::Animal::feed()
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type invoke(void (Base::*)(), const class V<T *> &) [Base = Animal, T = SpottedCat, V = vector]
```

Sorry about having to scroll to the right to see the types in that pretty-print, but they're pretty telling and should be looked at to see how this works. Note that both `Dog` and `StripedDog` containers properly fire the `Dog::feed()` member, while the `Cat` container properly fires the `Animal::feed()` base member since it provides no override.

Good luck, and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you are doing something like this, you would store them all in a single vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> animals;
```

If `Animal` defines a `feed` method, iterating over it simply means calling that function:

```
animals[i]->feed();
```

If you want to call specific functions based on types, you'll need to do some casting:

```
std::shared_ptr<Dog> pDog = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Dog>(animals[i]);
std::shared_ptr<Cat> pCat = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Cat>(animals[i]);
// other casts
if (pDog)
{
    // do something with a dog
}
else if (pCat)
{
    // do something with a cat
}
// etc
```

If you really wanted to store all of the `animals` in additional `vector`s, you can do that by wrapping the whole zoo:

```
class Zoo
{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> animals;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Dog>> dogs;
    // other vectors
public:
    void AddDog(const Dog& d)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Dog> pD = std::make_shared<Dog>(d);
        dogs.push_back(pD);
        std::shared_ptr<Animal> pA = std::static_pointer_cast<Animal>(pD);
        animals.push_back(pA);
    }
};
```

It doubles the number of pointers you are storing in memory, but pointers are fairly cheap.  Then you can pass the whole zoo, or individual animal types without the need to do the casting every time.

Comment: But there _is_ a need to retain the concrete type of `Doggies` and `Catties` for other types of processing.  If the zoo is huge, and you only need to "_walk the `doggies`"_, for example, then doing an extra downcast like this on every `Animal*` is inefficient.  There is little need to go through the whole `zoo` and check each animal to see if it is a `Dog` -- then _walk_ only those guys -- better to traverse the `doggies` collection only.

Comment: You are trading one inefficiency for another, or making your code far more complex than it needs to be simply because you made a poor design decision early on.  Conversely, if you really wanted to keep a separate list, you can still do so.  I'll edit to demonstrate.

Comment: Keeping animals in separate collections like this ("kennels"?) has other advantages too. Say the animals are ordered by size.  Finding the smallest cat with separate collections way is far easier than finding the smallest cat with one large collection of `Animal*`.

Comment: If they are already ordered, you simply need to find the first `Cat`.  Another way to do this is to add an enumeration to the `Animal` type that specifies which type it is.  Either way, the edit earlier accomplishes your original goal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pointers, which are quite cheap to copy, you could probably do:

```
vector< Animal * > zoo;

zoo.append( zoo.end(), doggies.begin(), doggies.end() );
// ditto with the others

feed( zoo ); // just receives *one* vector with animals to feed
```

---

Another option if you don't want to copy/merge the vectors:

```
void feed() {}

template< typename V >
void feed( const V& v )
{
    for( A* a : v )
    {
        // ...do something with 'a'
    }
}

template< typename V, typename V2, typename... Vs >
void feed( const V& v, const V2& v2, const Vs&... vs )
{
    feed( v );
    feed( v2, vs... );
}
```

Now you can call `feed( doggies, stripedDoggies, catties, spottedCatties );`.

Comment: But this is either difficult to maintain (if you keep `zoo` around and `doggies` changes).  If you just blow away the `zoo` every time `doggies` changes, then it becomes expensive to update.

Comment: @bobobobo True for the first version, but not for the second. Is the second one an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphic iterators? *shudder*

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Animal
{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct Elephant : Animal
{
    virtual void print() override { std::cout << "toot"; }
};
struct Cat : Animal
{
    virtual void print() override { std::cout << "meow"; }
};
struct Fox : Animal
{
    virtual void print() override
    { std::cout << "ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding"; }
};

#include <vector>

template<class T>
using simple_vector = std::vector<T>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Elephant> elephants(5);
    std::vector<Cat> cats(3);
    std::vector<Fox> foxes(1);

    polymorphic_range_container<simple_vector, Animal> animals;
    animals.push_back( std::make_pair(elephants.begin(), elephants.end()) );
    animals.push_back( std::make_pair(cats.begin(), cats.end()) );
    animals.push_back( std::make_pair(foxes.begin(), foxes.end()) );

    for(auto& animal : animals)
    {
        animal.print(); std::cout << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Implementation (basics):

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct iterator_base
{
    virtual void advance(int i) = 0;
    virtual T& get() const = 0;
    virtual bool equal(iterator_base const&) const = 0;
};

template<class ValueType, class Container, class Id>
struct polymorphic_iterator
{
    polymorphic_iterator& operator++()
    {
        impl->advance(1);
        if(container->is_end(*impl, id))
        {
            impl = container->next(id);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ValueType& operator*() const {  return impl->get();  }

    friend bool operator==(polymorphic_iterator const& l,
                           polymorphic_iterator const& r)
    {
        if(l.impl == nullptr) return r.impl == nullptr;
        if(r.impl == nullptr) return false;

        return l.impl->equal( *(r.impl) );
    }
    friend bool operator!=(polymorphic_iterator const& l,
                           polymorphic_iterator const& r)
    {
        return not (l == r);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr< iterator_base<ValueType> > impl;
    Container* container;
    Id id;

    friend Container;
    polymorphic_iterator(Container* pc, Id pid, decltype(impl) p)
    : impl( std::move(p) ), container(pc), id(std::move(pid))
    {}
};

template<template<class> class Container, class Base>
class polymorphic_range_container
{
private:
    using self = polymorphic_range_container;

    struct IRange
    {
        using piterator = std::unique_ptr < iterator_base<Base> >;
        virtual piterator begin() = 0;
        virtual piterator end() = 0;
    };

    template<class It>
    struct range : IRange
    {
        range(It p_begin, It p_end) : m_begin(p_begin), m_end(p_end) {}

        using typename IRange::piterator;
        piterator begin() override { return piterator{new iterator_impl(m_begin)}; }
        piterator end() override { return piterator{new iterator_impl(m_end)}; }

    private:
        struct iterator_impl : iterator_base<Base>
        {
            iterator_impl(It p) : it(p) {}

            virtual void advance(int i) override { std::advance(it, i); }
            virtual Base& get() const override { return *it; }
            virtual bool equal(iterator_base<Base> const& other) const override
            {
                iterator_impl const* pOther
                    = dynamic_cast<iterator_impl const*>(&other);
                if(nullptr == pOther) return false;
                else return it == pOther->it;
            }
        private:
            It it;
        };

        iterator_impl m_begin;
        iterator_impl m_end;
    };

    using container_type = Container< std::unique_ptr<IRange> >;
    container_type ranges;

public:
    template<class T>
    void push_back(std::pair<T, T> p_range)
    {
        ranges.push_back( std::unique_ptr<IRange>{new range<T>(p_range.first, p_range.second)} );
    }

    using iterator = polymorphic_iterator<Base, self, typename container_type::const_iterator>;
    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator{this, ranges.cbegin(), ranges.front()->begin()};
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator{this, ranges.cend(), {nullptr}};
    }

private:
    friend iterator;
    std::unique_ptr< iterator_base<Base> > next(typename container_type::const_iterator& p)
    {
        ++p;

        if(p == ranges.end()) return {nullptr};
        else return (**p).begin();
    }
    bool is_end(iterator_base<Base> const& it, typename container_type::const_iterator const& id)
    {
        if(ranges.end() == id) return false;
        else return (**id).end()->equal(it);
    }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ pointers are not required to be of the same size. C requires this for pointers to `struct`s. Additionally, the conversion from a derived type to a base type might involve some offset, e.g. for multiple inheritance. You can leave out *some* of the virtual functions under certain assumptions (e.g. the increment of the iterator) but probably not all of them.

Comment: Maybe you could even leave out the `nullptr` thing by just using the end iterator of the last element of `ranges` as the impl of the polymorphic iterator.

Comment: This can be modified to store pointers to containers instead of ranges. Currently, the whole `polymorphic_range_container` is invalidated when one of the iterators is invalidated.